# How to render all child components linked with app-router.module simulataneously in angular

Tags: angular

This may be a very basic question. The problem with the code is that, I want all the component to render simultaneously. Instead they render only when I click on their respective tabs. Anyone can give me a quick insight on what's happening here: 
Below is the 'app.component.html' file.

```
 <div class="container">

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">

    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/Tab1"> Tab1 </a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/Tab2"> Tab2 </a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/Tab3"> Tab3 </a>
    </li>


    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/Tab4"> Tab4 </a>
    </li>

  </ul>  

  <div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
 </div>
```